# What ways can I have my database create an archive entry when a table is updated or a row deleted?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table in my SQL Server 2012 database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Content] (
    [ContentId]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [Title]           NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Text]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Version]         ROWVERSION     NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]     DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate]    DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Content] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContentId] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Content_Subject_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Content]([SubjectId] ASC);
GO
```

When a user edits or deletes data in this table then all changes are lost. What I would really like is for the changes to be retained somehow.

Can anyone give me any suggestions or point me to a possible solution. I open to any kind of suggestion and would welcome some ideas. For example would it be reasonable to create an archive table and if I did that then how could I populate that table from inside the database. Is there a simple way that I could do this with triggers?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I have no DBA to ask for suggestions so I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you want to retain all the data why is the user allowed to edit existing information, why not simply adding a new record each time ?

Comment: I want to have show current data to the user but allow an admin person to go in, edit, update with some backup in case the admin made a mistake.

Comment: You could setup SQL Server to make a backup of the database each day, so in case something bad happens someone could restore the newest backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Enterprise edition of SQL Server, you can use Change Data Capture to keep a complete history of changes.  From the official documentation ([Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.110).aspx#Capture)):

Change data capture provides historical change information for a user table by capturing both the fact that DML changes were made and the actual data that was changed. Changes are captured by using an asynchronous process that reads the transaction log and has a low impact on the system.

Comment: I am using the SQL Azure version of SQL Server 2012 so unfortunately I don't think this exists.

Comment: @Adolfo Socorro `Change data capture` is only available in the Enterprise, Developer, and Enterprise Evaluation editions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with triggers, but my favorite solution is to do only "soft deletes".

A soft delete means you add a column, either a bit-type called "Deleted" or a datetime column (my fav) called "DeletedOn".

When the user "deletes" a row, instead of actually deleting it, you populate that column.  When you're querying the table, always filter out rows where "DeletedOn" is not null.   The rows are effectively deleted, but they're still there for historical purposes.

I see you've already got "ModifiedBy" and "ModifiedOn".   So you might consider "DeletedBy" and "
DeletedOn".

Answer (score 0):

If its no possible with [`Change Data Capture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.110).aspx#Capture) then you can use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187768.aspx) and [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189799.aspx) to archive the data before Updating or Deleting like

```
DECLARE @ID int,@CONTEXT_INFO varbinary(128)

SET @ID = 10
SET @CONTEXT_INFO =cast('ID='+CONVERT(varchar(10),@ID)
+REPLICATE(' ',128) as varbinary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @CONTEXT_INFO

--do Update / Delete that will fire the trigger

SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x0
```

here is the portion of the trigger to retrieve the value:

```
Create Trigger UpdDel
on Cuttingissue
Instead of Update,Delete
as
Begin
Begin Try

DECLARE @ID     int
       ,@sCONTEXT_INFO  varchar(128)
SELECT @sCONTEXT_INFO=CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR) 
FROM master.dbo.SYSPROCESSES WHERE SPID=@@SPID

IF LEFT(@sCONTEXT_INFO,9)='ID'
BEGIN
    SET @ID=RIGHT(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO),LEN(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO))-10)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('ID was not specified',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END
    Insert into Backup_tbl(Pktno,EType,Clg,Class,[Subject],Totscripts,Flag,CiDate)
    Select Pktno,EType,Clg,Class,[Subject],Totscripts,Flag,CiDate 
    from Cuttingissue where Pktno=@ID

/* Do Your Update/Delete here */ 

End Try
Begin Catch
Declare @ErrMsg Nvarchar(max),@Errseverity int
Set @ErrMsg=ERROR_MESSAGE()
Set @Errseverity=ERROR_SEVERITY()

Raiserror(@ErrMsg,@Errseverity,1)

End Catch
End
```